# Automatically update column values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in a SQL Server database with some columns along with

```
CreatedBy (varchar)
CreatedOn (datetime)
UpdatedBy(varchar)
UpdatedOn(datetime)
```

as standard columns. The `CreatedOn` and `CreatedBy` values are automatically populated as and when there is a new row added to this table (using default value approach).

Question: is there any out-of-the-box solution in SQL Server which can pupulate `UpdatedOn` and `UpdatedBy` values as and when row updates?

Comment: [Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189799.aspx) can accomplish this (assuming the `updatedby` value can be determined).

Comment: Although not "out-of-the-box", this is often done via triggers like Alex suggested.

Comment: You should edit your question to explain that you can't use Triggers and why.

Comment: It was clearly mentioned as out-of-the-box. Do you still think it is worth listing exclusion list of database objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from adding a trigger as mentioned by Alex K et all., you could also add a RowVersion column. This data type was previously called TimeStamp, but unfortunately the name is misleading.

This will give you the **UpdatedOn** smalldatetime timestamp, but not the UpdatedBy information.

If you want to convert the RowVersion colunm into a Date & Time format, you need to do a bit of work;

### 1. Create a table "UpdateTimeStamp" with three columns

(CreatedDate Smalldatetime, NewRowVersion, OldRowVersion) like this:

`Create Table dbo.UpdateTimeStamp(
    OldRowVersion binary(8), 
    CreatedDate DateTime constraint DF_UpdateTimeStamp_TimeStamp Default getdate(),
    NewRowVersion ROWVERSION CONSTRAINT PKUpdateTimeStamp PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
)`

Insert the first row manually

`Insert into dbo.UpdateTimeStamp(OldRowVersion, CreatedDate) VALUES (0x0000000000000000, '2000-01-01')`

### 2. Create a SQL Agent job

Which inserts one row in the table every one minute.

Make step 1 run this code:

`Insert into dbo.UpdateTimeStamp(OldRowVersion) SELECT TOP (1) NewRowVersion FROM dbo.UpdateTimeStamp ORDER BY NewRowVersion DESC`
 Set the schedule to run every 1 minute.

### 3. Join

Join the UpdateTimeStamp table to your table with a between join claus like this:

```
SELECT top 10000 mt.*, uts.CreatedDate AS ModifiedDate FROM dim.MyTable MT 
LEFT JOIN dbo.UpdateTimeStamp uts ON MT.DT1RowVersion > OldRowVersion AND MT.DT1RowVersion <= NewRowVersion
ORDER BY uts.CreatedDate
```

HIH.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I am behind out-of-the-box solution. Your approach is not clear to me fully though.

Comment: I've edited my reply a bit, and here is also a link to a post that I've written:
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98312/how-to-convert-timestamp-rowversion-to-a-date-and-time-in-ms-sql/98313#98313

Answer (score 1):

You can add a trigger like the one below. This trigger works if multiple rows are updated are the same time. Please notes it assumes you have added an identity column to your source table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].UpdateTrans ON [dbo].YourTable
   FOR UPDATE
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON 
   UPDATE  yt
   SET    UpdatedBy = SUSER_SNAME() ,
          UpdatedDate = GETDATE()
   FROM   DELETED d
      INNER JOIN YourTable yt ON yt.YourTableId = d.YourTableId
```

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned by Alex K. in the comments on the OP. This can be handled by a trigger object on the table.

Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateTable
ON table
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
[YOUR UPDATE CODE HERE]
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. I am behind out-of-the-box solution. Sorry I can't use triggers because of transnational size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) to do the same, below is the sample code (not tested, just a pseudo)

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].UpdateTrans 
ON [dbo].YourTable
FOR  UPDATE
AS 
      UPDATE YourTable 
      SET UpdatedBy= SYSTEM_USER
         , UpdatedDate = GETDATE()
     WHERE YourColumn IN (SELECT DISTINCT YourColumn FROM Inserted)
```

But it is not wise to use triggers on warehouse database, here is a article about [reasons to avoid Triggers](http://devproconnections.com/sql-server/reasons-avoid-triggers)

For better performance, I would recommend you to update `UpdatedBy` and `UpdatedDate` at the same time when you are updating any row.

You can read more about Triggers [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-Sql-Server).

Comment: please don't use that trigger link ever. The script is garbage, because it  only works when rows are inserted 1 by 1

Comment: Thanks for your post. I am behind out-of-the-box solution. Sorry I can't use triggers because of transnational size.